# Trying to change opacity in css onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to make onclick function make opacity from 0 to 1 so that .dropdown-content doesn't show before full height.

```
$(".fa-bars").click(function() {
        $(".fa-times").toggle();
        $("header").css("height", "100%");
        $("header").css("transition", "height 1s ease-in");
        $("header").css("grid-template-rows", "50px 400px");
        $("header").css("grid-row-gap", "20px");
        $("header").css("grid-template-areas", "'dp logo start' 'dc dc dc'");
        $(".dropdown-content").css("display", "grid");
        $(".fa-bars").css("display", "none");
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lambsbaaacode/uax6oe94/24/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to utilize the [`transition-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) CSS property, and [CSS specificty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#Understanding_the_cascade) to trigger the visiblity of menu items (inside of `.dropdown-content`) after the menu is open.

Because we know that the menu's open animation takes one second to complete (ie `height 1s ease-in`), we can delay the visiblity of menu items by one second to achieve the desired result.

The key idea here is to introduce a CSS "modifier class" (ie `.open`) which adds greater specificity to the `header` and `.dropdown-content`. This modifier:

- specifies the styling when the header is in an "open" state and
- specifies opaque/visible styling of the descendant `.dropdown-content` when header is in the open state

In SCSS, that could be written as:

```
header {  
  transition : height 1s ease-in;

  /* Define the dropdown-content transition styles on opacity, where
  the opacity delay causes opacity of menu items to change after menu
  animation (of 1sec) is complete */
  .dropdown-content  {  
    opacity:0;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    display:block;
  }

  /* CSS modifier class for "header.open" causes height to change
  when open class applied */
  &.open {
    height:100%;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 400px;
    grid-row-gap:20px;
    grid-template-areas:'dp logo start' 'dc dc dc';
  }

  /* When open modifier class applied to parent header, items in the
  .dropdown-content child are set to be opaque/visible */
  &.open .dropdown-content {
    opacity:1.0;
  }
}
```

With the SCSS above, you would then simplify your script to:

```
$(".fa-bars").click(function() {

    /* Add open modifier class to apply new CSS defined above and
    delay visiblity of dropdown-content content */
    $("header").addClass("open");

    $(".fa-times").toggle();
    $(".fa-bars").css("display", "none");
    event.preventDefault();
});
$(".fa-times").click(function() {

    /* Remove open modifier class to hide menu and items */
    $("header").removeClass("open");

    $(".fa-bars").toggle();
    $(".fa-times").css("display", "none");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Now, the menu items inside of `.dropdown-content` are only visible after `header` animation is completed. A working example [can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/oxeh8cqw/) - hope that helps!